# fastify schema validation with trim

Tags: node.js, jsonschema, ajv, fastify

I have written a schema as follows

```
input: {
            type: "string",
            allOf: [
                {
                  transform: [
                    "trim"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  minLength: 1
                }
            ],
            transform: ["trim"],
            trim: true,
            description: "Input",
            minLength: 1,
            maxLength: 3
        }
```

I want to accomplish 2 things - I want to trim the input and I want to validate that the trimmed input has minLength = 1.
I tried all the different configurations I came across for doing this, but none of them have worked so far. I am using fastify version 3.0.0, and I believe it uses ajv validator for doing the transform and validation. The validation part is working, however the trim has not happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` is not a standard json-schema feature.

So you need to configure `ajv` to get it working:

Notice that `allOf` array is executed sequentially, so if you move the `min/max` keyword at the root document, the spaces will be evaluated!

```js
const Fastify = require('fastify')
const fastify = Fastify({
  logger: true,
  ajv: {
    plugins: [
      [require('ajv-keywords'), ['transform']]
    ]
  }
})

fastify.post('/', {
  handler: async (req) => { return req.body },
  schema: {
    body: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        input: {
          type: 'string',
          allOf: [
            { transform: ['trim'] },
            { minLength: 1 },
            { maxLength: 3 }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

fastify.inject({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/',
  payload: {
    input: '   foo   '
  }
}, (_, res) => {
  console.log(res.payload);
})
```

Comment: I am facing  this issue . https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-keywords/issues/164 any pointers to resolve would be great

Comment: Reply on the issue, it is a matter of incompatible versions

Comment: Can this method be used with fluent-json-schema plugin?

Comment: Yes, you can - but you need to use the `S.raw()` method

Answer (score 4):

Install ajv-keywords using below cmd

```
npm i ajv-keywords
```

Import 'ajvKeywords' in code as follows

```
import ajvKeywords from 'ajv-keywords'
```

Pass on ajv instance to ajvKeyword

```
const ajv = new Ajv({
    useDefaults: true,
  })


 ajvKeywords(ajv, ['transform'])
```

And use in schema as follows

```
schema: {
    body: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        input: {
          type: 'string',
          transform: ['trim'],
          allOf: [
            { transform: ['trim'] },
            { minLength: 1 },
            { maxLength: 3 }
          ]
       }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Working as expected....