# fluent-json-schema with transforms in fastify schema validation

Tags: json, fastify

I am using [fluent-json-schema](https://github.com/fastify/fluent-json-schema) for input validation. However I was wondering whether we can have custom function/hook before doing certain validations. For example let's take a very simple json such as;

```
`
   {
       "loginid:"",
       "password":""
   }
`
```

In this case additionally to the provided validation methods I would like to;

1. Trim() the data so that whitespaces are removed. May be I can have a custom transform as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63304596/fastify-schema-validation-with-trim) (is it possible in fluent-json-schema library)?
2. Then validate for empty string ("") as well.

Is there a way to do this using  fluent-json-schema